# AzureML: publish pipelines

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have published an ML pipeline using AzureML SDK, and then triggering thepipeline from an external service using the REST endpoint.
Is there a way, by which I can re-publish the pipeline, keeping the REST endpoint unchanged?